# How do I recover a deleted file from an iPod Touch running OS 4.1

Tags: ios

How do I recover a deleted file from an iPod Touch running OS 4.1?

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a recent enough backup in iTunes, you can't. But if you do have a recent backup in iTunes, you'll have to do a full restore (by clicking the "Restore" button in iTunes) to get the file back.